# Android Studio - NetworkOnMainThreadException in object constructor

Tags: android, parsing, object, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I get a error of NetworkOnMainThreadException in the line of `AVObject brandObj = query.getFirst();` After did some searches about the error, I think I should use something like Asynctask. But couldn't figure out how to do it.

`AVObject` is same as `ParseObject`

```
public class Product {
    Product(AVObject object) {
        try {
            AVObject brandObj = query.getFirst(); // this one is making network request
        } catch (AVException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Should I `extends AsyncTask<AVObject, Void, AVObject>`

Then

```
@Override
protected AVObject doInBackground(AVObject... objects) {
    return null;
}
```

But not sure what should I write in `doInBackground`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: in doInBackground you should write query.getFirst(). It is the method that is making a network request.

Comment: put your code that need to be executed on another task

Comment: In short, yes. Assuming `query.getFirst()` is making a network request, you cannot run it on the UI (main) thread. Create an `AsyncTask<Void, Void, AvObject>` and run `return query.getFirst()` in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Do you mean I don't need the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

> NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when an application attempts to
>   perform a networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown
>   for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher.

You cannot perform any networking on your main thread because it may block the UI. Hence, you should do everything in a separate thread.

AsyncTask is one of the easier solutions. Setup your AsyncTask (follow some tutorials/guides) and put your networking code into doInBackground() method, which runs on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, an object's constructor does not perform disk I/O or network I/O. In your case, it does.

So, every piece of code that is calling `new Product(...)` needs to be put into a background thread (plain thread, RxJava chain, `JobIntentService`, `AsyncTask`, etc.). `Product` itself would not change.

Comment: Hi. Any posts I can take a look?